# Pyspark calculate mean over whole column with list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column including lists like this:

```
| value                   | 
|:----                    |
| ["1", "23", "18", "9"]  |
| ["62", "47", "6"]       |
|["34", "61", "5"].       |
```

is there a way for calculate the mean overall with pyspark? as a result i would like to have following value: 26.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the lists and average over the whole column:

```
mean = df.select(
    F.explode('value').alias('value')
).select(
    F.avg(F.col('value').cast('int'))
).head()[0]
```